# Laravel eloquent how to parse data inside the query where attribute

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have following issue. 
I need to get rows from database where price is lower than given number.
I can do it this way:

```
DB::where('price', '<=', $given_number)->get();
```

but the problem is that inside price cell I have number with added signs like $ for dollars or Euro sign. I know how to parse the string in PHP to extract only numbers - filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) , but how can I do this inside the query from Laravel? How can i pre-parse this 'price' attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
$price = filter_var($given_number, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$products = Product::where('price', '<=', $price)->get();
```

Is there more information that you left out?

Comment: no, I need to parse 'price' row in the database and compare it with that $price variable which is parsed. But 'price' in database is like 34$

Comment: might I suggest that you alter the values in your database so that they are numbers instead of strings? that looks like a highly unusual way to store values in the DB.

Comment: I guess you could do `DB::where('price', '<=', '$'.$given_number)->get()` but it is going to do a string comparison and not a numeric comparison...